# Android ZIP folders

Tags: android, zip

I use this code to ZIP folders including inner folders :

```
public boolean zipFileAtPath(String sourcePath, String toLocation) {
// ArrayList<String> contentList = new ArrayList<String>();
final int BUFFER = 2048;
File sourceFile = new File(sourcePath);
try {
BufferedInputStream origin = null;
FileOutputStream dest = new FileOutputStream(toLocation);
ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
        dest));
if (sourceFile.isDirectory()) {
    zipSubFolder(out, sourceFile, sourceFile.getParent().length());
} else {
    byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(sourcePath);
    origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(getLastPathComponent(sourcePath));
    out.putNextEntry(entry);
    int count;
    while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
        out.write(data, 0, count);
    }
}
out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
return false;
}
return true;
}

private void zipSubFolder(ZipOutputStream out, File folder,
int basePathLength) throws IOException {
final int BUFFER = 2048;
File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();
BufferedInputStream origin = null;
for (File file : fileList) {
if (file.isDirectory()) {
    zipSubFolder(out, file, basePathLength);
} else {
    byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
    String unmodifiedFilePath = file.getPath();
    String relativePath = unmodifiedFilePath
            .substring(basePathLength);
    Log.i("ZIP SUBFOLDER", "Relative Path : " + relativePath);
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(unmodifiedFilePath);
    origin = new BufferedInputStream(fi, BUFFER);
    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(relativePath);
    out.putNextEntry(entry);
    int count;
    while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
        out.write(data, 0, count);
    }
    origin.close();
 }
}
}

public String getLastPathComponent(String filePath) {
String[] segments = filePath.split("/");
String lastPathComponent = segments[segments.length - 1];
return lastPathComponent;
}
```

It works fine when folder looks like :

- Folder

  - txt file
  - jpg file
  - txt file

It also works fine when folder looks like :

- Folder

  - txt file
  - Folder

    - txt file
  - txt file

However in this case :

- Folder

  - txt file
  - Folder

    - txt file
    - jpg file
  - txt file

it starts endless loop, when ZIP file continuously increases.

I noted, that it happens because this loop :

```
 private void zipSubFolder(ZipOutputStream out, File folder,
 int basePathLength) throws IOException {
 .....

 while ((count = origin.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
        out.write(data, 0, count);
    }
 ....
 }
```

doesn't stop in the case, described above.

Any ideas why this can happen ? Thanks )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

I save ZIP file inside the same folder, that is zipped. So it starts to zip the ZIP file itself, saving new ZIP file inside again and again and again.

Not sure, if it's clear, but anyway, pay attention where do you save ZIP file.